# How to get the updated Document reference after batch write in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document which I updated using batch update, how to get the document reference or it's data after commited.

```
DocumentReference d = db.collection("posts").document(p.getUserId()).collection("userPosts")
                     .document(p.getDocId());

batch.update(d,"commentCount", FieldValue.increment(1));



batch.commit().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Log.d("post","Successfully batch writteen");
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
                    resultIntent.putExtra("docId", p.docId);
                    //Need result document here
                    resultIntent.putExtra("commentCount", task.getResult());
                    setResult(RESULT_OK);
                    finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d("post","Failed batch write");
                    finish();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Which `document reference` are you referring to?

Comment: @AlexMamo `d` document

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't understand you. Why to get a reference that's already in your code?

Comment: i mean after commiting i need the values inside that Document @AlexMamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment:

> i mean after commiting i need the values inside that Document

If you need the new updated values after the batch write ends, you need to make a `get()` call on the **exact** same reference. In order to be sure that the batch write is complete, you should get that document from inside the callback, from inside the `onComplete()` method.

```
d.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

Comment: is this ok `DocumentSnapshot s = d.get().getResult();` ?

Comment: No, it's not, you should add a complete listener again. Everything in Firebase is about listeners. You cannot get it without it.